# Gillespie Stochastic Simulation in Discrete Time using R

Tags: r, simulation, markov, stochastic-process

I'm simulating a Stochastic Simulation for Epidemiology. How do I simulate it in a discrete time? I managed to obtain for continuous time using the coding below.

```
library(GillespieSSA)    
parms <- c(beta=0.591,sigma=1/8,gamma=1/7)    
x0 <- c(S=50,E=0,I=1,R=0)    
a <- c("beta*S*I","sigma*E","gamma*I")    
nu <- matrix(c(-1,0,0, 1,-1,0, 0,1,-1, 0,0,1),nrow=4,byrow=TRUE)   
set.seed(12345)    
out <- lapply(X=1:10,FUN=function(x) ssa(x0,a,nu,parms,tf=50)$data)
out
```

How should I alter the coding to get discrete time? Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The Gillespie algorithm (see [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/j100540a008)) basically simulates the trajectory of a [continuous-time Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctmc) (it is a [discrete-event simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-event_simulation) approach).

Broadly speakig, this means that each event in `out` is associated with a continuous time, and that **this is inherent to the simulation approach you used** (i.e., *not* easy to change).

However, **you can easily find out the *state* of your model at discrete points in time**: it is the state of the model *before* the first event with a higher time stamp.

**Example**: You observe reaction event `e_1` at time `1.932..`, `e_2` at time `1.999892..`, and `e_3` at time `2.00892..`. The state of the model at time `t=2.0` is the state *after* event `e_2` occurred and *before* event `e_3` occurred.